# KubernetesMockServer - remove responses before every test

Tags: java, kubernetes, fabric8

Is there any way to remove all responses of KubernetesMockServer (that are created with `server.expect().withPath`) before every test?

```
@BeforeMethod
public void before() {
    // some code
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the kubernetes-client itself we are doing something like:

```
@Rule
public KubernetesServer server = new KubernetesServer();
```

This pretty much causes the server to recreated after each test, allowing us to start clean